# Winjs access to file in a localState folder

Tags: file, winjs

I created a project for windows 8 in javascripts/html.

Now I want load a file that I stored in LocalState folder:

```
"C:\Users\%name%\AppData\Local\Packages\%package_name%\LocalState"
```

i use a function for check a file:

```
console.log(function load(C:\Users\%name%\AppData\Local\Packages\%package_name%\LocalState\filename.jpg));
```

I get an error `APPHOST9623 RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND`

How can I fix the error?

thanks

Comment: Can you write here the code you use? we can't tell you the problem if you don't tell us the code.

Comment: I use a library in javascript for calculate md5 of file:
and i recall function that have parameter a path of file:
`var x = localFolder.path + "\\" + fileName;
console.log("file esistente " + x);
console.log(md5_file(file));`
I believe that with your suggest i can't use the function.

Comment: I want know how to load in variable file!

Comment: sorry but really it is not clear what you are trying to do. you need to post your code in a way that we can understand

Comment: I use this library http://phpjs.org/ for get the md5 of a file.
Now the function md5_file have with parameter a path of the file. My file is store in this path C:\Users\%name%\AppData\Local\Packages\%package_name%\LocalState\. If i use this path in the function i have the error write before!Sorry if i explain badly

Comment: ok, but what is "file"? do you need a string with the content of the file you read?

Comment: the function want the path of file!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.getFileAsync("fileName.jpg")
.done(function (file) {
    //data is a file object
},
function (error) {
    //error if file does not exist
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the path to the file, then try in this way:

```
var file = localFolder.path + "\\" + fileName; console.log("file esistente " + x); 
console.log(md5_file(file));
```